# Forcing net positions in nwdiag

Tags: plantuml

I am having problems with the following diagram:

```
@startuml
!include <office/Concepts/firewall>
!include <office/Devices/modem>
!include <office/Devices/router>
!include <office/Devices/modem>
!include <office/Devices/workstation>
!include <office/Devices/workstation_pc>
!include <office/Servers/application_server>
!include <office/Servers/database_server>
!include <office/Servers/virtual_web_server>
!include <office/Servers/virtual_server>
!include <office/Servers/file_server>
!include <office/Servers/physical_host_solid_blue>

nwdiag {
    ISP_A [ shape = cloud];
    ISP_A -- routerA;
    ISP_B [ shape = cloud];
    ISP_B -- routerB;

    Firewall [description = "<$firewall>\nOPNsense"];

    network RED1 {
        description ="RED1/WAN1"
        address = "192.168.1.0/24"
        color = red
        routerA [address = "192.168.1.1", description = "<$modem>\nFast Fiber\nDynamic IP"];
        Firewall [address = "192.168.1.254"]; /'remove this to have second diagram'/
    }

    network RED2 {
        description ="RED2/WAN2"
        address = "192.168.2.0/24"
        color = red
        routerB [address = "192.168.2.1", description = "<$modem>\nSlow DSL\nFixed IP"];
        Firewall [address = "192.168.2.254"];
    }

    network ORANGE {
        description ="ORANGE/DMZ"
        address = "192.168.9.0/24
        color = orange
        Firewall [address = "192.168.9.254"];
        WebServer [address = "192.168.9.8", description = "<$virtual_web_server>\nwebserver"];
        OtherServer [address = "192.168.9.7", description = "<$virtual_server>\nuserver"];
    }

    network GREEN {
        description ="GREEN/LAN"
        address = "192.168.7.0/24
        color = palegreen
        Firewall [address = "192.168.7.254"];
        cinderella [address = "192.168.7.12", description = "<$workstation>\ncinderella"];
        controller [address = "192.168.7.x", description = "<$workstation_pc>\ncontroller"];
        workstation [address = "192.168.7.90", description = "<$file_server>\nSynology"];
    }
    
    group {
        color = "SkyBlue";
        description = "<$physical_host_solid_blue>\nLXD Server";
        Firewall;
        WebServer;
        OtherServer;
    }

}
@enduml
```

[image]

Problem is I would like to have both red networks on top, something like what I get if I delete `Firewall` entry in RED1 (but then I miss a connection, of course):

[image: PlantUML diagram]

Essentially I should force link between Firewall and RED2 to go up instead of down, but I didn't find a way to do it.

I also tried defining `Firewall` before usage, but it doesn't seem to change anything.

Can someone help, please?

Comment: The source code you provided produces the second image (whereas I think the first image is the one you're having trouble with). Can you add the source of the first image please?

Comment: @Fuhrmanator: sorry, my bad. I added back the line to produce first diagram. to go to second just delete the marked line.